# my sql how do sum() that will every raw till that raw?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query that returns me 2 col as the following:

(I get the total col with `count(*)` )

```
date     total  
1,2010     2  
2,2010     5  
3,2010     3  
4,2010     7  
5,2010     6  
6,2010     6
```

I would like to do some query on the results that I got that will do sum on the total but in each row it will do sum till that row so I will get:

```
date     total  
1,2010     2  
2,2010     7  
3,2010     13  
4,2010     20  
5,2010     26  
6,2010     32
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to query a query, you can always `CREATE VIEW`. Then run a `SELECT` from the view.

Comment: please add the query you performed to get the first set of data.

Comment: Can you edit the title question? I'm having trouble following you. Thanks!

Comment: Without both the original data and the query that gave you your first result I don't see how this question is answerable. We're not able to guess what your original data looked like. Are you able to post this please?

Answer (score 0):

You may use user variable to calculate the sum.

```
SELECT id, date, @t:=@t + total AS total
FROM table t1, (SELECT @t:=0) t2
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query and a user-variable to do this:

```
set @running_total := 0;
select date, @running_total := @running_total + total
from
(
  select date,count(*) as total
  from your_table
  group by date
  order by date
) s
order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I managed to get things done with JOIN:

```
mysql> select t2.date, sum(t1.total) from tt t1 join tt t2 on t1.date <= t2.date group by t2.date;
+--------+---------------+
| date   | sum(t1.total) |
+--------+---------------+
| 1,2010 |             2 |
| 2,2010 |             7 |
| 3,2010 |            10 |
| 4,2010 |            17 |
| 5,2010 |            23 |
| 6,2010 |            29 |
+--------+---------------+
```

and original table:

```
mysql> select * from tt;
+--------+-------+
| date   | total |
+--------+-------+
| 1,2010 |     2 |
| 2,2010 |     5 |
| 3,2010 |     3 |
| 4,2010 |     7 |
| 5,2010 |     6 |
| 6,2010 |     6 |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a cumulative sum.  The standard SQL way is with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.date,
       (select sum(total) from t t2 where t2.date <= t.date) as CumulativeTotal
from t
```

This is assuming that the date field is directly comparable, "2,2010" does not make sense to me as a date.  If this is intended to be "month,year", then it is not quite a date and you need to do extra work.  I strongly recommend that when strings represent dates, then you should use YYYY-MM or YYYY-MM-DD formats.